# Передача переменных методом GET между скриптами

Tags: php, get

Добрый день. Есть один вопрос. Я написал кое какой скрипт, который я прилагаю:

Соединяемся с базой

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Could not connect: " . 
mysql_error());
```

Вытаскиваем базу

```
mysql_select_db("test",$db);
```

Вытаскиваем таблицу со значениями

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT kod,model FROM phones",$db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Выводим все данные в упорядоченной форме

```
echo "Ваш номер телефона: ".$subno. "<br /> Код товара: ".$myrow["kod"]. "<br />Модель телефона: ".$myrow["model"];
```

Заносим запись с БД в переменную для отправки в другой скрипт

```
$s = $myrow["kod"];
```

Формируем ссылку

```
$data="file.php?var=$s&var2=privet";
```

Выводим ссылку

```
echo "<a href=".$data.">File.php</a>"
```

Все прекрасно работает. Но для того, чтоб данные передались, мне нужно перейти по ссылке. А нельзя сделать так, чтоб они автоматически передались. И я открыл файл,  и увидел в нем нужные мне переменные?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**php-http-redirect:**

```
header("Location: file.php?var=$s&var2=privet");
```

Вызывать до любого иного вывода.

**js:**

```
print '<script type="text/javascript">window.location='."file.php?var=$s&var2=privet".'</script>';
```

**curl:**

```
if( $curl = curl_init() ) {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'file.php?var=$s&var2=privet');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $out = curl_exec($curl);
    echo $out;
    curl_close($curl);
  }
```

Comment: Вот такое выдает:
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Open-server\domains\localhost\script\testing.php:8) in C:\Open-server\domains\localhost\script\testing.php on line 32

Comment: > Вызывать до любого иного вывода. 

Я же написал. До этой строки не должно быть ни принтов, ни html вставок. Даже пробелов нельзя.
Если никак не получается, можно запихнуть js код:

print '<script type="text/javascript">window.location='."file.php?var=$s&var2=privet".'</script>';

но это костыль.

Comment: Поговаривают еще с cURL что то замутить можно...

Comment: можно. Но для этого данный модуль должен быть и у вас должны быть к нему доступы.

    if( $curl = curl_init() ) {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'file.php?var=$s&var2=privet');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        $out = curl_exec($curl);
        echo $out;
        curl_close($curl);
      }